# HTML table caption inside div

Tags: html, css, html-table, caption

I have what seems to be a simple question: I have a table that I am making as an accessible friendly element, including using the `<caption>` tag for the table title. This is all fine, but my element titles are styled into a ribbon which has the following structure:

```
<div class="ribbon"><h2></h2></div>
```

I have read that the caption for the table **must** come directly after opening the table tag, so my question is: can I wrap my caption in a div and it still be interpreted as a valid caption for a table like so?

`<div class="ribbon"><caption>Title Here</caption></div>`

Comment: What is the `div` for?  Can you apply your style (or id) to the `caption` tag instead>

Comment: The outer div is necessary but what about doing something like: `<caption><span>Title</span></caption>` would that be valid? All I need is 2 block elements, the styling can be applied to whatever.

Comment: I've just done it as I suggested above and it works like a charm, but now the question is: is it still valid? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. That HTML is invalid.

From [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-caption-element.html#the-caption-element):

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   As the first element child of a table element.

Comment: Although I did just run it through W3C validation and it passed, why does that mean then? Does it just do syntax analysis but not semantic?

Comment: @WilliamHand — Exactly what input did you give it? The validator should report an error if you use an element somewhere it is not allowed.

Comment: I'm currently building the site so I put in the dev URL and it validated fine, no errors. It is still inside a table, but just inside another div so it becomes Table > Div > Caption rather than Table > Caption. I have made an alteration and tried it Table > Caption > Span which gets the effect for me, is this valid? (See comment on question).

Comment: I'm not using HTML5, I'm using XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Comment: Captions have never been allowed as child elements of divs, and divs have never been allowed as child elements of tables. HTML 5 just has the most readable expression of that.

Comment: A span may be a child element of a caption.

Answer (score 2):

No, so use a span inside a caption.